# Access to submit buttons inside a php isset function

Tags: php

i am trying to access an input type "submit" in an isset function.
The following code is executed when i'm pressing on the "delete" icon. It then displays the shown question if you really want to delete this entry. How can i access both buttons? Do nested isset functions work? Thanks for your help

```
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])){
    
    echo 'Do you want to delete '.$_GET['delete_id']. '? <br>';
    
    
    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete_yes" value="Yes" style="margin: 10px; position: absolute; top: 60px; "></input>';   
    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete_no" value="No" style="margin: 10px; position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 55px; "></input>';
    
}
if(isset($_GET['delete_yes'])){
    echo 'deleted';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access both buttons"?  Does your second `if` block work as expected?  Can't you repeat that logic for the "no" button?

Comment: It's just an example. Normally i'd like to delete a row from a mysql table, but I only wanted to try if i can print something when pressing the YES button. Nothing happens when i'm pressing it

Comment: It looks like you just forgot to include the `<form>` then.  Look at your delete button (which isn't shown here) as an example.

Comment: thanks to you too!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the buttons in a form passing the id as a hidden value:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])){

    echo 'Do you want to delete '.$_GET['delete_id']. '? <br>';

    echo '<form method="get">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="'.$_GET['delete_id'].'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete_yes" value="Yes" style="margin: 10px; position: absolute; top: 60px; "></input>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete_no" value="No" style="margin: 10px; position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 55px; "></input>';
    echo '</form>';

}
if(isset($_GET['delete_yes'])){

    echo 'deleted '.$_GET['delete_id'];
}
```